# PyTorch - how to find the max values at certain indices ?? (PyTorch equivalent of tf.math.unsorted_segment_max)

Tags: pytorch

In PyTorch, I need to efficiently find the max values at certain indices.  TensorFlow has a built in function `tf.math.unsorted_segment_max` to achieve this, I'll borrow an example from their documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/unsorted_segment_max:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import tensorflow as tf

data = tf.constant([5, 1, 7, 2, 3, 4], dtype=tf.float32)
segment_idxs = tf.constant([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], dtype=tf.int64)
num_segments = 2

max_at_idxs = tf.math.unsorted_segment_max(data, segment_idxs, num_segments)

print('\n' + 'max_at_idxs: ')
print(max_at_idxs)
```

output:

```
max_at_idxs: 
tf.Tensor([5. 7.], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
```

I realize that logic-wise I could use a loop like this:

```
import torch

data = torch.tensor([5, 1, 7, 2, 3, 4], dtype=torch.float32)
segment_idxs = torch.tensor([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], dtype=torch.int64)
num_segments = 2

max_at_idxs = torch.full(size=(num_segments, ), fill_value=-9999.9999, dtype=torch.float32)
for i, segment_idx in enumerate(segment_idxs):
    max_at_idxs[segment_idx] = torch.max(data[i], max_at_idxs[segment_idx])
# end for

print('\n' + 'max_at_idxs: ')
print(max_at_idxs)
```

However in my actual application `data` and `segment_idxs` are ~200,000 items long and this has to be done often so a loop is way too slow.

Similar questions have been asked in the PyTorch forum before, noteably:
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-perform-segment-max/33374
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-there-a-pytorch-implementation-of-tensor-flow-segment-softmax/77433/4
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-equivalent-to-tf-unsorted-segment-sum/25275
but none of these resolves my concern, so I figured I'd ask here.

I keep figuring there has to be a way to do this with fancy indexing, possibly in combination with `torch.where` or some other built-in function, but I can't seem to work it out.

Also, I keep looking at the `torch.maximum` function, trying to figure a way to use the 2nd parameter as indices rather than values, but I can't find a way to work this out either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `c` segments and data of length `m`, the solution I propose is to create a "masking array" of size `[c,m]` where `masking_array[i,j]` has value 0 if the segment index for item `j` is equal to `i`, and negative infinity otherwise. This masking array can then be added to the original `data`, leaving relevant data values unchanged but making out-of-segment values equal to negative infinity (thus excluding them from possible selection in the `max` operation).

No loops, though does bear the memory usage of `c`x`m` so if you have a huge number of segments could be somewhat costly.

Let `idx` be a vector of length `m` of integer groups in range `[0,c]`
and let `data` be a vector of length `m` of arbitrary values:

```
def segment_max(data,idx):
    # infer dimensions from data
    m = data.shape[0]
    c = (torch.max(idx) + 1).int()

    #1. expand each vector to 2-D array
    data_exp = data.unsqueeze(0).expand(c,m)
    idx_exp  = idx.unsqueeze(0).expand(c,m)

    #2. Create sequential integer matching array
    match = torch.arange(c).unsqueeze(1).expand(c,m)

    #3. Create mask
    mask = torch.where(match == idx_exp,float(0),-torch.inf)

    #4. Add mask to data_exp
    data_masked = mask + data_exp

    #5. Get max along m dim
    segment_max,segment_max_idxs = torch.max(data_masked,dim = 1)
    return segment_max
```